# How to change endpoint at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to change endpoint at runtime

example: GET localhost:8080/old-endpoint

how to set same endpoint url to GET localhost:8080/new-point

i found that "${dynamic.endpoint}" and read from application.properties but i don't want it. I'm trying to edit endpoint according to if else blocks.

I know that path variable or request param or control from application.properties but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `/old` and `/switch` endpoints.

After calling `/switch`, `/old` stops working (because of `unregisterMapping`) and `/new` works instead (because of `registerMapping`).

The logic of new method handler is passed as `Method` from java reflection.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/testing")
public class TestingController {
    @Autowired
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mappingHandler;

    @GetMapping("/switch")
    public void switchHandler() throws Exception {
        RequestMappingInfo oldInfo = RequestMappingInfo.paths("/api/testing/old")
                .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
                .build();
        mappingHandler.unregisterMapping(oldInfo);

        RequestMappingInfo newInfo = RequestMappingInfo.paths("/api/testing/new")
                .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
                .build();
        Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("oldHandler");
        mappingHandler.registerMapping(newInfo, this, method);
    }

    @GetMapping("/old")
    public void oldHandler() {
        System.out.println("old endpoint");
    }
}
```